# How to create an external link from emberjs loop?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm looping through several items in a model. For each item I would like to create an external link to a page in my application that is not using emberjs. I thought this would be trivial but its not working the way I thought it would work.

This is what I have:

```
<tbody>
   {{each model itemViewClass=App.ColorView}}
</tbody>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="colorTemplate">
   <tr>
                <td>{{date}}</td>
                <td><a href="/myapp/colors/{{id}}/shades">{{name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</script>

App.ColorView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'colorTemplate'
});
```

I thought this would create links like these:

```
/myapp/colors/5/shades
/myapp/colors/45/shades
/myapp/colors/6/shades
...etc.
```

However, the link is being created like this:

> localhost:8080/myapp/colors/%3Cscript%20id='metamorph-33-start'%20type='text/x-placeholder'%3E%3C/script%3E56%3Cscript%20id='metamorph-33-end'%20type='text/x-placeholder'%3E%3C/script%3E/shades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should implement a itemController to the {{#each}} collection view. In that itemController you  can use a computed property to generate the url as

```
url : function () {
 return "/myapp/colors/"+this.get('id')+"/shades";
}.property()
```

Here is a [Sample Bin](http://jsfiddle.net/Raj_Michaels/unzLW/5/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you should use `{{bindAttr href="url"}}` for this. `url` is a method that generates url